# Get FxCop to suppress warnings for a whole type?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, fxcop, suppressmessage

How can I suppress FxCop warnings for a whole type?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{     
    public static class Serializer<T>
    {
        public static string Serialize(T obj)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        public static T Deserialize(string str)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

I tried this, but it is not working for me:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design",
    "CA1000:DoNotDeclareStaticMembersOnGenericTypes", Scope = "Type",
    Target = "ConsoleApplication1.Serializer'1")]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, this will not work. FxCop only processes suppressions that are declared against the same target as a detected violation. If it finds a violation on your `Serialize` method, the only `SuppressMessage` attributes that will "hide" that violation are either one declared on the method itself or one whose `Target` property identifies the method.

If you want to suppress a CA1000 violation for each of your static methods in the `Serializer<T>` class, you will need to do this by creating a `SuppressMessage` attribute for each of those methods.

> [@Matt Faus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819977/matt-faus): What's the point of the `Scope` argument then?

The `Scope` argument lets FxCop know what kind of thing the `Target` argument represents. For example, if `Target` is `"A.B.C"`, does that refer to a namespace named `A.B.C` or a class named `C` in the namespace `A.B`? `Scope` should probably be named something like `TargetKind`, but that, unfortunately, does not change what it actually represents...

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32358753/1497596).