# How to suppress code analysis messages for all type members?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, roslyn, fxcop

Let's say I have an enumeration of all currencies:

```
public enum CurrencyType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// United Arab Emirates dirham
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    AED = 784,

    /// <summary>
    /// Afghan afghani
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    AFN = 971,

    /// <summary>
    /// Albanian lek
    /// </summary>
    [EnumMember]
    ALL = 008,

    ...
}
```

VS 2015 code analysis keeps complaining about 100 violations of [CA1709](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182240.aspx) for every individual member.

This is an useful rule by itself, and I do not want to disable it; yet it is of not much help in this specific case, as `CurrencyType` is public and is used in a whole lot of other projects.

I can suppress the message; however, VS only offers me to suppress it for every individual member - meaning that I'll have 100 `[SuppressMessage(...)]` lines, which will clutter the code.

Is there any way to suppress all CA1709 for all `CurrencyType` members, while not suppressing it for all other code in this project, without having to write 100 `[SuppressMessage(...)]`?

There is a `Scope` parameter of `SuppressMessageAttribute`, but the documentation is unclear on that one. I've tried placing both

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly", Scope = "type", Justification = "Currency codes are defined in ISO standard.")]
```

and

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly", Scope = "member", Justification = "Currency codes are defined in ISO standard.")]
```

on `CurrencyType` itself. Neither does work.

Comment: Is this enum in a file by itself? If so you can have Style Cop [ignore the file](http://sethflowers.com/blog/force-stylecop-to-ignore-a-file/)

Comment: You can add these to the Code Analysis Dictionary so that they're recognized as capitalized abbreviations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There is no such problem with StyleCop, it seems that `SuppressMessageAttribute` on type changes analysis behavior for all members. CA1709 is integrated VS Code Analysis (FxCop) warning, not StyleCop one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to suppress a rule for a whole class or enum in this case and have the suppression apply to all of its members, unfortunately.

But what you can do, is create a `CodeAnalaysisDictionary.xml`, add it to your project containing the Enum and setting its 'Build action' propery to `CodeAnalysisDictionary`:

[image]

Once you have set this up, you can add the abbreviations and case exceptions to the dictionary like this:

```
<Dictionary>
      <Acronyms>
         <CasingExceptions>
            <Acronym>AED</Acronym>
            <Acronym>AFN</Acronym>
            <Acronym>ALL</Acronym>
            <Acronym>...</Acronym>
         </CasingExceptions>
      </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

While these exceptions will apply to any element in the code with these acronyms in them, they will prevent the CA1709 warnings from showing up.

See the documentation for more information on the exceptions you can setup using the dictionary files:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx#bkmk_dictionaryacronymscasingexceptionsacronym

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no way to do this without individual suppressions. The `Scope` argument lets the code analysis engine know what kind of thing the `Target` argument represents. For example, if the Target is "A.B.C", does that refer to a namespace named `A.B.C` or a class named `C` in the namespace `A.B`? "Scope" would perhaps have been better represented by a name like "TargetKind", but that, unfortunately, does not change what it actually represents.

Given the ugliness of the suppressions in this case, you might want to generate them into `GlobalSuppressions.cs`, then move them into a separate file like `CurrencyTypeMemberNameSuppressions.cs`, which you could (optionally) nest as a file under the file containing your `CurrencyType` enum in your project structure in Visual Studio. Not ideal, but maybe the best choice of a bad lot at this point...

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260745/1497596).

Answer (score 3):

what about `#pragma warning disable CA1709`?
to reactivate you can use `#pragma warning restore CA1709` but if this enum is the only one type in your file you can leave that out.

Comment: This worked for me in VS2017. But using SupressMessage on the enum type for members flagged for CA1707 and CA1712 also worked for me in VS2017 (I didn't specify a Scope parameter).